# Alexa skill "Sorry, I am unable to fulfill your request on this device" In skill purchase on iOS device

Tags: in-app-purchase, alexa-skills-kit

When I try to test purchase an In-Skill Purchase for my Alexa skill in beta, I get "Sorry, I am unable to fulfill your request on this device" as a response on my iOS device, but on my Echo Dot is works perfectly fine. I can't seem to find any documentation regarding ISP unavailability on mobile devices. Any idea as to why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this exchange from the forums, an Alexa Developer Advocate confirmed in November 2019 that ISP purchases could not be completed from mobile devices.

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/217514/are-in-skill-purchases-disabled-in-the-mobile-alex.html